# How to scan code recursively in sonarqube

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have some code in different folders like folder a, folder b,folder c....and all these three folders are in folder name "sonar". if I want to scan all these folders at a time using sonarqube how can I do it. will it be fine if I keep sonar-project.properties file in folder sonar? or do I need to keep sonar-project.properties in all the folders like in folder a, folder b, and folder c individiually

Answer (score 2):

Usually properties should be there for every folder for making analysis on every folder.

You can also try the following approach if it suits your needs and if it is not a big learning curve:
Prerequisites:
ANT Knowledge
Sonar API

Advantages:
1. Single/Central approach for every code analysis
2. Can avoid sonar.properties for every project/source folder

In this approach, write an ANT script that accepts dynamic parameters

## Sample:

```
<target name="setsonarproperties" description="Setting the sonar properties">
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="${projectVersion}" />
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${targetProduct}_${projectVersion}" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="${targetProduct}" />
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="${hostUrl}" />
    <property name="sonar.login" value="${hostUserName}" />
    <property name="sonar.password" value="${hostPassword}" />
    <loadfile property="textFile" srcfile="${buildOrder}" />
    <for param="line" list="${textFile}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
        <sequential>
            <echo message="@{line}" />
            <copy todir="${sourcePath}/sonarsources/@{line}">
                <fileset dir="${sourcePath}/@{line}">
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Next also set the sonar user name and password details:
Run analyser:

```
<target name="sonar" depends="setsonarproperties" description="executing sonar">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file 
            in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
    </taskdef>
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is more into ANT. is this is the same way for different languages like mainframes too @Vijay Reddy

Comment: I haven't tries for Mainframe but most likely it would be same if you have the API for mainframe...

Comment: And also do I need to have a sonar-project.properties?. also, where I can keep this ant code. is there any way I can contact you